# ¿Cómo resetear/vaciar un array y establecer una tabla html a su estado inicial?

Tags: javascript, html5

estoy trabajando con tabs, pero tengo los siguientes detalles.
planteamiento: tengo tres pestañas de un tab, en cada pestaña mapeo un array diferente para mostrar la info en tablas html y las filas de cada tabla son plegables...

Detalle: Al cambiar de pestaña del tab tengo que establecer toda la vista de cada una a su estado inicial, estoy seteando los array en vacío, y si lo hace pero las tablas html mantienen los datos iterados, solo se actualiza el array pero no la tabla, y esta debería no tener nada....ayuda....

***this._bodyTabla***1 : es un método donde itero el array para generar la tabla html
Muestro parte del código para setear mis arrays:

```js
resetTabs(e) {
    if (e.target.selected === 0) {
      this.arrayPestaña2 = []
      this.arrayPestaña3 = []
      console.log('Tab Pestaña 1', e.target.selected)
      console.log('this.arrayPestaña2',this.arrayPestaña2)
      console.log('this.arrayPestaña3',this.arrayPestaña3)
      this.requestUpdate(this.arrayPestaña2);
      this.requestUpdate(this.arrayPestaña3);

    } else if (e.target.selected === 1) {
      this.arrayPestaña1 = []
      this.arrayPestaña3 = []
      console.log('Tab Pestaña 2', e.target.selected)
      this.requestUpdate(this.arrayPestaña1);
      this.requestUpdate(this.arrayPestaña3);
      
    } else if (e.target.selected === 2) {
      this.arrayPestaña1 = []
      this.arrayPestaña2 = []
      this.requestUpdate(this.arrayPestaña1);
      this.requestUpdate(this.arrayPestaña2);
    }
    
  }
```

```html
<web-tab-transactional label="Group of tabs 3" variant="divider" @selected-change="${(e) => this.resetTabs(e)}">
          <web-tab-transactional-item heading="Pestaña 1"> 
            ${this._bodyTabla1}
          </web-tab-transactional-item>
          <web-tab-transactional-item heading="Pestaña 2">
            ${this._bodyTabla2} 
          </web-tab-transactional-item>
          <web-tab-transactional-item heading="Pestaña 3">
            ${this._bodyTabla3} 
          </web-tab-transactional-item>
      </web-tab-transactional>
```

Comment: Creo que te falta alguna etiqueta. Eso no tiene pinta de ser solo javascript y html

Comment: Estoy trabajando con componentes lit-Element y javaScript

Answer (score 0):

Conozco 3 formas poniéndole el Arr1.lenght = 0 o con Arr1.splice(0, Arr1.length); que igual sigue usando el Arr1.lenght o podría ser con .pop este ultimo quita el ultimo elemento del array podrías ponerlo en un bucle

```
for (let i = Arr1.length; i > 0; i--) {
     Arr1.pop();
}
```

Algo así, te recomiento usar el primero y no complicartela pero igual te deje la otra info como dato curioso

Comment: De acuerdo te agradezco tu comentario, y como podría hacer para que la afectación del seteo en vacío del los array afecte también a la tabla html que genere al mapear previamente el array, es decir el seteo del array funciona, e imprimo su valor y es [], pero la tabla html aun conserva los valores iterados...

Comment: esa parte si no estoy muy seguro por que no soy mucho de web pero creo que esto te puede servir  https://es.acervolima.com/como-eliminar-todas-las-filas-de-una-tabla-en-javascript/#:~:text=Esto%20se%20puede%20hacer%20usando%20JavaScript.&text=En%20primer%20lugar%2C%20establezca%20la,las%20filas%20de%20la%20tabla.

Comment: Vale, te lo agradezco mucho, saludos....